# How do I read a doc file ( which have different language characters e.g Japanese) using php

Tags: php

Well, I'm showing a uploaded document content with following PHP code. If the document have English language then it's showing perfectly but when I try to upload a different language .e. g Japanese then it's showing following characters. Why it's showing this different characters ?

```
w��RL}tk�f R��\0�k�B0�0D0�00_0......................
```

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
function getPlainTextFromDocFile($filename){
if ( file_exists($filename) ) {
if ( ($fh = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false ) {
$headers = fread($fh, 0xA00);
# 1 = (ord(n)*1) ; Document has from 0 to 255 characters
$n1 = ( ord($headers[0x21C]) - 1 );

# 1 = ((ord(n)-8)*256) ; Document has from 256 to 63743 characters
$n2 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21D]) - 8 ) * 256 );

# 1 = ((ord(n)*256)*256) ; Document has from 63744 to 16775423 characters
$n3 = ( ( ord($headers[0x21E]) * 256 ) * 256 );

# (((ord(n)*256)*256)*256) ; Document has from 16775424 to 4294965504 characters
$n4 = ( ( ( ord($headers[0x21F]) * 256 ) * 256 ) * 256 );

# Total length of text in the document
$textLength = ($n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4);

$extracted_plaintext = fread($fh, $textLength);

# if you want the plain text with no formatting, do this
return $extracted_plaintext;

# if you want to see your paragraphs in a web page, do this
//echo nl2br($extracted_plaintext);

}

}
}

$file1 = "japanese.doc";
$filename = "$file1";
echo $contentDoc = getPlainTextFromDocFile($filename);

//$fileLocation = "myfile.txt";
//$file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
//fwrite($file,$content);
//fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: @JakeGould I use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` but it's still showing different characters.

Comment: @JakeGould  is there any other way without COM function ?

Comment: @JakeGould I'm checking it but can you tell me what is the actual issue in my function ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the encoding of the page to UTF-8.

This line should be the first line of your PHP file.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I did it but still it's showing me different characters.